# How to I find where a certain number would fit in a row of values in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an array of 10 numbers in numerical order ranging from 1-100 in Excel Column B-K. In column A, I have a single number from 1-100. I want to find out where the value in column A would fit in the values from B-K.

For example, for the following 10 numbers (in descending order), the value 58 would fit in the 4th position (between 60 and 54). How would I write a formula to do this for many different values?

80  75  60  54  32  21  20  15  12  5

Comment: You can use MATCH for this.

Comment: As @TimWilliams suggested use `=MATCH(A1,B1:K1,-1)+1`